# Android: Display Details of The Target Object Clicked

Tags: android, parameter-passing, click

I have contactmanager.java to display read and display the contact person from phone. when I click on certain contact list, it doesn't show up the exact contact person details. May i know why?

```
  /*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public final class ContactManager extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

    public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

    private Button mAddAccountButton;
    private ListView mContactList;
    private boolean mShowInvisible;
    //public BooleanObservable ShowInvisible = new BooleanObservable(false);
    private CheckBox mShowInvisibleControl;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created. Responsible for initializing the UI.
     */



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_manager);

        // Obtain handles to UI objects
        mAddAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        mShowInvisibleControl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showInvisible);

        // Initialise class properties
        mShowInvisible = false;
        mShowInvisibleControl.setChecked(mShowInvisible);

        // Register handler for UI elements
        mAddAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mAddAccountButton clicked");
                launchContactAdder();
            }
        });
        mShowInvisibleControl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "mShowInvisibleControl changed: " + isChecked);
                mShowInvisible = isChecked;
                populateContactList();
            }
        });

        mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
        mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        // Populate the contact list
        populateContactList();
    }



    /**
     * Populate the contact list based on account currently selected in the account spinner.
     */
    private void populateContactList() {
        // Build adapter with contact entries
        Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        String[] fields = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
        };


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
                fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
        mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
     *
     * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
     */
    private Cursor getContacts()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        Log.i("Uri ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI" + ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null);

        String[] projection = new String[]
                {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                //ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_PHONE
                };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        //String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible.get() ? "0" : "1") + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        return this.managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }

    /**
     * Launches the ContactAdder activity to add a new contact to the selected account.
     */
    protected void launchContactAdder()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactAdder.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("TAG", "You clicked item " + id + " at position " + position);
        // Here you start the intent to show the contact details
     // selected item
        //String contactDetails = (String)(mContactList.getItemAtPosition(position));
        //Uri contactDetails = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        //Cursor emailCur = getContacts();
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        int phone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
        //String email = emailCur.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));


        // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListContact.class);
        SingleListContact.PutDetails(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, name, phone,null );

        Log.i("Show Contact Clicked: ",  name);
        // sending data to new activity
        //i.putExtra("Contact Person", contactDetails);
        startActivity(i);

    }


}
```

And the SingleListContent.java

```
package com.example.android.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleListContact extends Activity{

    static int ContactPhone;
    static String ContactID, ContactName, ContactEmail;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_contact_view);

        EditText txtContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txtContact.setText(ContactName);

//        EditText txtContact2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
//        txtContact2.setText(ContactPhone);

        EditText txtContact3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        txtContact3.setText(ContactEmail);


// 
//        Intent i = getIntent();
//        // getting attached intent data
//        String contact = i.getStringExtra("contact");
//        // displaying selected product name
//        txtContact.setText(contact);
        Log.e("test", ContactID +" & " + ContactName); 


    }

    static void PutDetails (String id, String name, int phone, String email)
    {
        ContactID = id;
        ContactName = name;
        ContactPhone = phone;
        ContactEmail = email;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have done it totally wrong that's why it is not working.

in first code snippets you are passing wrong values in PutDetails method.

for name you are passing ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME which is not the name it is a string representing the contactName column of the phonebook . So to get name use the following.

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

and for email you are sending a null value so the email will be definitely null. if you want email for the contact similarly use

```
String email = emailCur.getString(
              emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
 String emailType = emailCur.getString(
              emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
```

And here i can see that you are only using name and email. But if you wanted phone number then you have to find that too because here you are not sending any phone number but only the postion.

Comment: where i should two the cursor.position....and String name? in contactmanager.java?

Comment: What is the different between SharedPreference and PutDetails?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake while making the last comment. I actually wanted to write Putextra not sharedpreference. Here instead of using static setter method you can easily use Intent.Putextra to pass values to next activity. this is a good practice. you can get data in second activity by calling getextra. For these methods see android api docs.

Comment: after put in ur code, i still can't access the email, any idea on emailCur variable?